# Establishing a matroid for higher local fields K/L((t₁,..,tₙ))

Tags: local-fields, matroid-theory

In the theory of [matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid), the [Cohen structure theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen_structure_theorem) and theorem on transcendence degree that each field is algebraic over a field of the form k(x₁,..., xₙ), as well as [Noether normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma), fall into a common vein of theorems establishing that an extension is "small" (algebraic, finite, zero dimensional) over a "free" object (k(x₁,...,xₙ) and k[[x₁,...,xₙ]] in these examples).

I am looking for a similar theorem involving Laurent series k((x₁,...,xₙ)) and local fields. It seems like there should be a matroid for this situation too.

For any complete valued field L (field with valuation, potentially higher dimensional) with norm ν : L ⭢ ℝ, if $L$ is nonarchimedian then there is a map φ : ℤ̂ ⭢ L, producing a map ℤₚ ⭢ L for some prime, in turn producing a either map ℚₚ ⭢ L for some prime or ₚ ⭢ L for some prime. If $L$ is Archimedean then there is a map $ℝ ⭢ L$. Whichever the base (ℝ, ℚₚ, or ₚ), the map extends to a map ψ: K((t₁,...,tₙ)) ⭢ L, with $n$ maximal. I want to show that:

- L/K((t₁,...,tₙ)) is the completion of an algebraic extension of K((t₁,...,tₙ))

The matroid would have Laurent series as its "free" objects and completions of algebraic extensions as its "relative dimension 0" extensions, like this:

- Let $K ⭢ L$ be relative dimension 0 with respect to the space of valuations or Berkovitch spectrum. Then L is the completion of an algebraic extension of $K$.

The other thought I had is the possibility of a left adjoint analogous to the symmetric algebra (and which is related to the free object in n dimensions for a matroid). I was hoping that there would be a left adjoint to the forgetful functor from complete valued fields to their modules which produces Laurent series.

Comment: The special characters used for formulae in this question render as blank boxes. Please use LaTeX.